# VSCode debugger error "command 'extension.pickNodeProcess' not found"

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have updated VSCode from July 2021 release to August 2021 release (Version 1.60.0).

After the update, I can't debug Node.js process with this error.

I reinstalled VSCode, but no change.

How can I solve this?

[image]

My launch.json and index.js is below.

- launch.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach by Process ID",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:extension.pickNodeProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

- index.js

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, () => console.log('Server http://localhost:3000'));
```

- Node.js version
  14.17.2.

Comment: I found a temporary solution.
Instead of F5, Ctrl + Shift + P and then, search and run 'Debug: Attach to Node Process'.